# Title of plot partially italicized in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

[image]

The title has a strange format in my scatter plot. Is there anything I can do to change it to a just normal title?

```
plt.title("Log: $ Pledged vs. Rank By $ Pledged", style="normal")
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the dollar sign (`$`) is the trigger for [MathText](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) in matplotlib, you need to escape it to display `"$"` as a usual text character: `"\$"`

```
plt.title("Log: \$ Pledged vs. Rank By \$ Pledged")
```